# How can I add a horizontal grid from the bottom of the page without an offset?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to add only horizontal lines which will start from the bottom of the page and step toward the top with a gap of 100pt. There is no need for the steps to match the height or top of the page.

I am trying the following.

```
\documentclass[parskip=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:329pt,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay][x=1pt,y=1pt]
        \noindent\draw[step=90pt,gray,very thick] (0,-329pt) grid (432pt,0pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\noindent\blindtext
\end{document}
```

What i get is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with two compilation runs, you an easily refer to the bottom left as `current page.south west` and thereafter run a `\foreach`-loop that draws a line per `100pt`. The code would be:

```
\documentclass[parskip=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:329pt,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,x=1pt,y=1pt]
        \foreach \position in {0,100,...,500}
        {
            \draw[cyan,thick] ($(current page.south west)+(0,\position)$) -- ++(432,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\noindent\blindtext
\end{document}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `$(current page.south west)+(0,\position)$` what are the dollar marks for

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi the dollar marks tell `TikZ` that there is a calculation of coordinates following. It means add the position of the `south west` (lower left) corner of the `current page` with 0 for the x coordinate and the `\position` which is the variable from the `\foreach`-loop for the y coordinate.

Comment: i just tried this without for loop `\draw[cyan,thick] ($(current page.south west)+(0,100pt)$) -- ++(432,0);` it says `Package pgf Error: No shape named (current page is known.`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi if you have a new question, how the `(current page)` node works, please open a new question, in general it will work outside a loop, too. Therefore I guess you probably have an issue with your syntax.